# using custom hostname domainname for virtual network

Tags: ubuntu, azure, hostname

I have set up a virtual network for all my machines to use. One of them is headnode, which will have a public ip address, all others will have internal ip addresses only. I really don't like the xxxx.xxxxx.xxxxx.internal.cloudapp.net. In fact, one of the program I am using complained about the hostname is longer than HOST_NAME_MAX, 64. It will look a lot better if I can just use machine1.local, machine2.local or something like this. One solution I can think of is to change it with hostname on each machine. Is there cleaner way to do it than changing it after vms are deployed? I am using resource management templates. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Currently Azure only supports the xxx.xxx.xxx.internal.cloudapp.net suffix, allowing customers to bring their own suffix is something we have on our backlog but we don't presently have a date we can share.  If you were to change the suffix on the individual VMs, they won't resolve unless you deploy your own DNS solution as the internal.cloudapp.net is where the host's DNS records are registered.

Hth,
Gareth